# Check precisely if two rectangles with double coordinates intersect

Tags: algorithm, intersection

I was playing arround with hitboxes and ended up with following data:

```
final double targetSmallestX = targetCenter.getX() - targetHalfWidth;
final double targetSmallestY = targetCenter.getY() - targetHalfHeight;
final double targetHighestX = targetCenter.getX() + targetHalfWidth;
final double targetHighestY = targetCenter.getY() + targetHalfHeight;
final double sourceSmallestX = sourceCenter.getX() - sourceHalfWidth;
final double sourceSmallestY = sourceCenter.getY() - sourceHalfHeight;
final double sourceHighestX = sourceCenter.getX() + sourceHalfWidth;
final double sourceHighestY = sourceCenter.getY() + sourceHalfHeight;
```

What i want to do is to check, if the two given rectangles `target` and `source` are intersecting with each other. Could have done it like this

```
Rectangle target = new Rectangle(targetSmallestX, target.width, targetSmallestY, target.height);
Rectangle source = new Rectangle(sourceSmallestX, source.width, sourceSmallestY, source.height);
target.intersect(source);
```

But this would require me to work with integers.
All the algorithms I came up with seemed too long and complicated for such a seemingly simple task. Does anyone have an idea for a smart approach for this?

**EDIT:**
Current approach

```
(targetSmallestX < sourceSmallestX + this.width)
&& (sourceSmallestX < (targetSmallestX + target.width))
&& (targetSmallestY < sourceSmallestY + this.height)
&& (sourceSmallestY < targetSmallestY + target.height);
```

Does this check leave any possible constellations in which it wouldn't work correctly?

Comment: Take a look at the source code for `Intersect` here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Rectangle.cs

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Two rectangles intersect if and only if their x-values overlap, and their y-values overlap. You can write an "overlap" function that accepts `range1Start`, `range1Width`, `range2Start`, and `range2Width` and returns whether those ranges intersect. Then, call that twice for x-values and y-values.

Comment: Are the rectangles oriented parallel to the x/y axis?

Comment: @userunknown yes. I am not going to go through the trouble of calculating that stuff with angles

Comment: @pkpnd theoretically it is java. But what does it matter? Look at it as pseudo language. The algorithm is the same anyways.

Comment: @Basti Because Java already implements what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you can use `java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D` which represents coordinates with floating-point precision. Precisely, its inner class `java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Double` uses `double` to represent the coordinates.

```
Rectangle2D target = new Rectangle2D.Double(targetSmallestX, targetSmallestY, target.width, target.height);
Rectangle2D source = new Rectangle2D.Double(sourceSmallestX, sourceSmallestY, source.width, source.height);
target.intersect(source);
```

Comment: Ty. Didn't know Rectangle has a Double implementation.